# Macro comands not excuteing in batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, doskey

i am currently in the process of a project and  i want to use DOSKEY commands i have in a bat file, for example  run program of change direcorties theses commands all work on in my CLI. just wondering if theres a way to commands like  note =notepad.ext 1$("useing this just as a simple example") to run in the bat file ,does the file need  permissions ,what the process to have my bat files run the commands i make?

i tried multiple  command and   topics and looked  at chatgpt but  the problem wasnt really that well  described

Comment: Doskey does not create new commands. It kind of sits between the keyboard and the computer and "translates" the macros into the original code (well, technically not, but it's a good visualization). So there is no way to use those macros programmatically.

Comment: A common solution in batch files is to Use a method of defining variables as a macro which can accept arguments. A good Learning resource can be found at https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1827

Such macro's can range from simple to highly complex, and can be used in the place of almost any function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doskey macros can't be used/executed from batch files.

They can only be executed, when they are typed by the keyboard.

```
C:\Users> doskey mymacro=echo hello
C:\Users> mymacro
hello
C:\Users> echo mymacro | cmd /k
'mymacro' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

A workaround is to use batch files instead of doskey macros.

**note.bat**

```
@echo off
notepad "%~1"
```